# flink backpressure monitoring

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

From the beginning of our Flink project.

My cluster have suffered from low back-pressure because of heavy parsing code.

So I put monitoring script on the system which keep asking back-pressure status from the task manager. ( Which run every 20 seconds for getting the highest value and average )

By the way when I turn off the script running, I found increment of back pressure ratio become much less slower than when I using the script.

So is there any efficient way to get the back pressure status without losing performance ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe requesting back-pressure every 20 seconds would have a major impact on your workflow's performance.

Separately, if you've got available CPU cycles, then increasing the parallelism of the function(s) doing the parsing would be the next thing to try, to improve throughput.

Comment: The result is empirical. So that's the question I'm asking for. Same code under same cluster. And this cluster is the only working for single Flink job.

The background for thought is here, I'd like to know the reason too. :)

"In order to not overload the task managers with stack trace samples, the web interface refreshes samples only after 60 seconds."

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/monitoring/back_pressure.html

Comment: And Kkrugler could you let me know how many parallelism you are using relatively ? 

I'm using 480 parallelism and 480 Kafka partition. So it's nearly 1:1 pipeline from Kafka to parsing code.